# Connect my raspberry to my pc by usb

Tags: usb

I would like know if it's safe to connect my Raspbery Pi B+ to my PC by usb please (usb to usb), I want display the micro sd card of my raspberry on my windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work.  The Pi's USB ports are not OTG.

The Pi does not present itself as a hard drive to other equipment connected via USB.

You may be able to do what you want with a Bluetooth dongle.

You can view the SD card /boot partition on a Windows PC with a SD card reader (as the /boot partition is FAT).  You can't view the /root partition as that is in ext4 format which is not understood by Windows (you might be able to download software which lets Windows understand ext4).